# How do I center navbar text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
    </head>
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">                    
                    <ul  class="nav nav-pills-justified">
                        <li><a href "#">about</a></li>
                        <li><a href "#">blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href "#">portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href "#">contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js">
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

I want the **text** in the navbar to be centered-fixed-top.

Comment: JSfiddle please.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Please provide a jsFiddle: jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You know how the navbar is on the top, horizontal? ((well at least the one i have is)). I wanted the text "about, blog, portfolio, contact" to be centered on top. Idk how else to simplify what I am asking...

Answer (score 0):

Here i've posted simple navigation bar with centered nav text. you can use this...

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">

    <ul class="nav-pills-justified">
      <li><a href ="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href ="#">blog</a></li>
      <li><a href ="#">portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href ="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav-pills-justified
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-width:980px;
    background: #EDEDED;
    color: #000000;
    height: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.nav-pills-justified li
{
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav-pills-justified li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.nav-pills-justified li a:hover
{
    background: red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VYZsD/)

Comment: Sweet thanks! Also how do I use CSS in HTML? Is it:
<script type="text/css">
<!-- css code -->
</script>          ?

Comment: @user3223207 : No <script> is for javascript. you should mention like this <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="yourcssfilesrc.css" />. if this is answer is useful you can accept this answer as correct one..

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-pills-justified {
   height:50px;
   list-style-type:none;
  }
  .nav-pills-justified li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom:1000px;
  margin-left:250px;
  width:1px;
  font-size: 20px;
  }
  .nav-pills-justified li a {
  display: inline-block; 
  }
```